# Reorganizing dataframe in specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi all so I have 2 dataframe I am trying to merge and group in a particular order:

```
df1   
   LC_REF     Category      PRDGRP
0  17 1C      H         Ferrari,Lambo,Merc
1  17 1C      M         Doritos,Lays,Funyun
2  17 1C      P         Cats,Dogs,Rabbits
3  16 2C      H         Aston,Hyundai,Honda
4  16 2C      M         Cheeto, Vicks
5  16 2C      P         Rat,Pig,Flamingo
6  17 2C      M         See,Sea,Far


df2   
   LC_REF     Category      PRDGRP
0  17 1C         H         foo,bar
1  17 1C         M         foo,bar1
2  16 2C         H         foo,bar2
3  16 2C         M         foo,bar3
4  17 2C         H         foo,bar4
5  17 2C         M         foo,bar5
6  17 2C         P         foo,bar6
```

And I am looking merge them such that all M's of one LC_REF is stacked, then all H's, then all P's, then move onto the second LC_REF. Order does not matter but should be consistent. Hopefully this makes sense:

```
df3   
   LC_REF     Category      PRDGRP
0  17 1C       M         Doritos,Lays,Funyun
1  17 1C       M         foo,bar1
2  17 1C       H         Ferrari,Lambo,Merc
3  17 1C       H         foo,bar
4  17 1C       P         Cats,Dogs,Rabbits
5  16 2C       M         Cheeto, Vicks
6  16 2C       M         foo,bar3
7  16 2C       H         Aston,Hyundai,Honda
8  16 2C       H         foo,bar4
9  17 2C       M         See,Sea,Far
10  17 2C      M         foo,bar5
11  17 2C      P         foo,bar6
```

I've tried variations of concat and append to no avail:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

is almost close, but the LC_REF are out of order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `pd.concat` and `sort_values`:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_out['Category'] = df_out.Category.astype('category', categories=['M','H','P'], ordered=True)
df_out.sort_values(by=['LC_REF','Category'])
```

Output:

```
  LC_REF Category               PRDGRP
4  16 2C        M        Cheeto, Vicks
3  16 2C        M             foo,bar3
3  16 2C        H  Aston,Hyundai,Honda
2  16 2C        H             foo,bar2
5  16 2C        P     Rat,Pig,Flamingo
1  17 1C        M  Doritos,Lays,Funyun
1  17 1C        M             foo,bar1
0  17 1C        H   Ferrari,Lambo,Merc
0  17 1C        H              foo,bar
2  17 1C        P    Cats,Dogs,Rabbits
6  17 2C        M          See,Sea,Far
5  17 2C        M             foo,bar5
4  17 2C        H             foo,bar4
6  17 2C        P             foo,bar6
```

Comment: Crazy! I just tried something similar. Is there a way to preserve the original order?

Comment: Close... this was my first guess. The Category order is off.

Comment: I guess I don't understand.

Comment: @ScottBoston I'll keep playing with the sort_index, but my ideal output would preserve the LC_REF order in my original dataframe (17 1c,  16 2c, 17 2c) while also arranging the 'Category' column as M first, H and then P. However I may need to adjust my data to make it cleaner...

Comment: Oh.. I think we need to make Category an order Categorical type.

Comment: @ScottBoston I feel like I'm so close! Organizing by non alphabetical type is quite challenging it seems

Comment: @codeninja Okay, think you can use something like this.